# How many times can a Windows Update be postponed before a forced reboot of the machine is performed in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Assume the following:

1. A notebook running Windows 7 has automatic Windows Updates enabled, which is scheduled to both download and install updates
2. An update that requires a restart is downloaded and installed, at which point a dialog is displayed to the user. The dialog has two buttons; an option labeled "Restart", and another option labeled "Postpone". The user wishes to do just that, so they hit the "Postpone" button with the default time of 10 minutes selected and close the lid of the laptop, which is set to put it to sleep
3. Several hours later, the same user then wakes the notebook from sleep and is presented with the same dialog. Once again, they postpone the update and put the machine back to sleep
4. Finally, another couple of hours later they wake the machine - which then automatically restarts due to the pending Windows Update

So - my question. How many times can the "Postpone" button be clicked before Windows will automatically force the machine to reboot - does this time also take sleep/wake cycles into account, resulting in the forced restart described above?

Comment: "How many times can the "Postpone" button be clicked before Windows will automatically force the machine to reboot " Indefinitely as far as I know. I have done it for weeks.